# How do I find out what a Type 3 error is in a JavaScript Error object?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, ngrx-effects

I am using the npm serialize-error package to write JavaScript errors to a log file on my server when making an http request within an Angular/Ngrx app.

I am getting a type=3 within the JS error object when serialized. I can't find anywhere what that means. Does anyone know?

The code that does the serialization of the JS error can be found below but I'm not sure it's relevant.

What I'm really asking is what does it mean when a JS Error object contains a type=3?

This is the serialized data string (formatted for clarity) that gets printed:

```
        [err] => Array 
        ( 
            [_body] => Array 
            ( 
                [isTrusted] => 1 
            ) 
            [status] => 0 
            [ok] => 
            [statusText] => 
            [headers] => Array 
            ( 
                [_headers] => Array ( ) 
                [_normalizedNames] => Array ( ) 
            ) 
            [type] => 3 
            [url] => 
        )
```

This is the code that inconsistently throws the error (it works 95% of the time so its not just something in my syntax). But I can't troubleshoot it because I can't find any references for what a type=3 means:

```
@Effect() $teamLoadAction: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(TEAM_LOAD_ACTION)
  .switchMap((action) => this.team.get(action.payload))
  .map((res) => {
    return new NullAction();
  }
)
.catch((err) => Observable.of(new UserErrorAction(err)));
```

this.team.get is defined as (just an angular http.post):

```
get(data) {

    return this.http.post(
        this.config.hostUrl+'/api/team/get', 
        JSON.stringify(data))
      .map(
        (res) => {
        return res.json();
    }
      );
  }
```

This is the code inside the UserActionError handler that serializes the err value:

```
 import SerializeError  from "serialize-error";
 syserr(err): Observable<ApiState> {
    data = SerializeError(err);

    return this.http.post(
        this.config.hostUrl+'/api/account/syserr', 
        JSON.stringify(data) )
    .map(
        res => res.json()
    );
  }
```

Comment: It looks like `type` is an enum on the `HttpErrorResponse` of either `HttpEventType.Response` or `HttpEventType.ResponseHeader`, not that I think that will bring you any closer to discovering the issue...

Comment: Nice try but doesn't seem to be the issue. 3rd enum is a DownloadProgress update and these calls have nothing to do with any downloads.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, just seen you're using the old HTTP, not the newer HttpClient. In that case the enum is https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseType but 3 just means Error

Comment: Thanks, didn't pick up on that myself. But, yeah 3 - Error doesn't help much does it, LOL